# How to const map variables

Tags: c++

I have three variables int a,b,c which I use to select a value of a fourth variable d.

A short boolean example:

```
a=0, b=0, c=0 -> d=0
a=0, b=0, c=1 -> d=1
a=0, b=1, c=0 -> d=2
a=0, b=1, c=1 -> d=1
and so on...
```

I thought about creating a constexpr matrix to create the mapping. The down side is the it generates non readable code. Is there a better option?  Maybe some boost library or a known design pattern?

I am programming in c++11

Thank you :)

Comment: `std::map<std::tuple<int, int, int>, int>>`?

Comment: @NathanOliver not compile time.

Comment: What do you mean by 'generates non-readable code' You mean ASM is not readable, or you can't read your own code which you wrote?

Comment: we certainly cannot read your code, if you dont show it :P, seriously, creating some constexpr lookup is "the better way", please show your code

Comment: Are ranges (of `a`, `b`, `c`) contiguous as your boolean example, then you can flatten your map to a simple array.

Comment: is there an equation that links a,b,c and d?  You can then make that function a constexpr

Comment: The question is vague, but it sounds like you're looking for [pattern matching](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pattern_matching#Declarative_programming). There's nothing simple built into the language, but there are a few libraries ([Mach7](https://github.com/solodon4/Mach7), [MPark.Patterns](https://github.com/mpark/patterns), [simple_match](https://github.com/jbandela/simple_match/)) that try to make the code as clear and declarative as possible. Maybe you can take some hints from them about how to structure your code for readability.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can supply `a`, `b`, and `c` as template arguments, rather than function parameters, you could define a template with three `bool` arguments, and then supply explicit implementations for the combinations of interest, like this:

```
template<bool A, bool B, bool C> constexpr int index() { return -1; }
// Truth table
template<> constexpr int index< true, false,  true>() { return 9; }
template<> constexpr int index< true, false, false>() { return 24; }
...
```

Here is how you would invoke these functions:

```
cout << index<true,false,true>() << endl; // Prints 9
```

[Demo.](https://ideone.com/jVkM5D)